# NHibernate (3.1) subquery on subclass not joining base class table

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, subquery, joined-subclass

The following is an abstraction of an actual problem I'm having.

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Sub : Base
{
    public virtual string Bar { get; set; }
    public virtual Other Other { get; set; }
}

public class Other
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Sub> Subs { get; set; }
}
```

mapping:

```
<class name="Base" table="base_table" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <id name="Id" column="id">
    <generator class="assigned" />
  </id>
  <property name="Foo" column="Foo" />

  <joined-subclass name="Sub" table="sub_table">
    <key column="id" />
    <property    name="Bar"   column="Bar" />
    <many-to-one name="Other" column="other_id" />
  </joined-subclass>

</class>

<class name="Other" table="other_table" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <id name="Id" column="id">
    <generator class="assigned" />
  </id>
  <set name="Subs" inverse="true" lazy="true">
    <key column="other_id" />
    <one-to-many class="Sub" />
  </set>
</class>
```

The following fails to do the join on the joined-subclass inside the subquery:

```
Session.Query<Other>().Where(o => o.Subs.Any(s => s.Foo == "xyz"));
```

Sql

```
select
    other0_.id as id60_
from
    other_table other0_
where
    exists (
        select
            subs1_.id
        from
            sub_table subs1_
        where
            other0_.id=subs1_.other_id
            and subs1_1_.Foo=:p0
    );
:p0 = 'xyz' [Type: String (0)]
```

A GenericADOException is thrown because subs1_1_ (e.g. sub_table) in the subquery doesn't have Foo.
Is there something I have to do in Other's mapping to cause the Subs to be fully joined with Base in the subquery?

Comment: please don't use <pre> for formatting code

Comment: Do you have the exact SQL? It might just be lazy loading the Base properties.

Comment: Ok.. I've added the exact sql I'm getting.

Comment: did you mapped the base propperty of the entity you mapping?

Comment: Yes.. as you can see Foo is mapped in Base.

Comment: @TravisHeseman Did you find a solution to this ultimately? I am facing a similar problem and being compelled to used `table-per-hierarchy` which breaks in some other Linq situations.

Comment: I moved away from this project some years back and I honestly can't say if this has be resolved by the NHibernate team.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is an linq provider issue related to joined subclass mapping. The query works well for table per hierarchy. Try this:

```
<class name="Base" table="base_table" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>

    <discriminator column="Type" type="String" />

    <property name="Foo" column="Foo" />

    <subclass name="Sub" discriminator-value="Sub">
        <property    name="Bar"   column="Bar" />
        <many-to-one name="Other" column="other_id" />
    </subclass>
</class>

<class name="Other" table="other_table" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <set name="Subs" inverse="true" lazy="true">
        <key column="other_id" />
        <one-to-many class="Sub" />
    </set>
</class>
```

Unfortunatelly joined subclass cannot be replaced by table per hierarchy in all cases...

There are some issues registered in NH jira that looks similar ([NH-2564](http://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2564?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel), [NH-2491](http://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2491?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)) but not sure they are really related.

EDIT: 
The same problem is with HQL: `from Other o where exists(from o.Subs s where s.Foo = 'xyz')` therefore it is not an issue related to linq provider.